# What happens when a "stuffed-string" is the original transmission?

Tags: networking, bitstuffing

Take this original string, and let the flag be "01111110" (0-bit stuffing):

010**0111110**101

After the bit stuffing, the resulting string is the same, but the meaning of the sequence 01111110 is different: it is interpreted as an original flag which has been stuffed.

I know I am wrong, I would like to know where my logic is flawed.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly then the meaning is completely changed by the context the string is interpreted in (interpreted by different pieces of code) - the happenstance that the original string ends up being a sub-string has no bearing.

Comment: But whenever the interpreter finds 5 consecutive 1s, it is seen as a substring which originally was the flag, but was stuffed (by adding a 0 between the last two 1s).